# How to avoid multiple observable requests to the backend when using async pipe in template

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, async-pipe

I am trying to return individual Arrays to each entry in mat-option-select conditional to some conditions.
However when i use getFoos(rowIndex, matSelectIndex) | async. It cause multi request to the backend. Here is my call stack,

**In HTML Template:
**

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let foo of getFoos(rowIndex, matSelectIndex) | async"
                                [ngClass]="{'inactiveFoo': !foo?.status}"
                                [value]="foo.id">
                      <span [innerText]="foo.name"></span>
                    </mat-option>
```

The method getFoos in my ts file:

```
private obsFoos: BehaviorSubject<Foo[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Foo[]>([]);
private Foos$: Observable<Foo[]> = this.obsFoos.asObservable();

public getFoos(rowIndex: number, selectionIndex: number): Observable<Foo[]> {
    const someId: string = this.getId(rowIndex, selectionIndex);
    
    if(this.Foos$ && someId) {
      return this.Foos$.pipe(switchMap((foos) => {
        const missedFoo$: Observable<Foo[]> =      this._ksFoosService.getById(someId).pipe(
          tap((res) => this.obsFoos.next([...foos, res])),
          map(() => foos),
        );
        return iif(() =>
          someId && !foos.some(x => x.id === someId),
          missedFoo$,
          this.Foos$
        );
      }
      ))
    } else { return this.otherFoos$ }
  };
```

The problem is the getById will execute 20 times. Because this.obsFoos.next([...foos, res]) add the missing Foo later (when it get a response) and angular template keep calling the function.

What i did try is using shareReplay() and use some other rxjs methods to make the getById wait until it get a response. I also tried to avoid using iif().

I hope you could help guys.

Comment: that's why they recommended NOT to use function in template. You can call that getFoo in onInit then assign the value in ngFor

Comment: @Jimmy : Believe me or not, i have to do it this way.  I have to return custom Lists depend on the parameter in the function

Comment: Actually you don't, Angular is used by many many company including Google. Which means, Angular must be able to solve the issue. So I suggest you refactor your code. There're many ways to overcome the problem so my advise is dig deeper, you can take a look at this article: https://indepth.dev/posts/1299/using-angular-in-the-right-way-template-syntax

Comment: Here if you want to keep your function: https://itnext.io/its-ok-to-use-function-calls-in-angular-templates-ffdd12b0789e

Comment: @jimmy thanks anyway. I have read both of them and none could solve my case (depend on my understanding). 
My Component is custom so it is mix between Mat-Table and Mat-Select and Reactive forms. 
Table come with 2 Columns. This first one has a text and the second has Mat-Select. Every row could have one or more mat-select, and every mat-select is warped with FormControl and could have different select list depend on their value in the formControl.
And i cant simplify the complexity because the data structure coming from the server...

Comment: If I understand correctly. You have a select/dropdown that get its option depend on some input text? like choosing a country, changing the country will change its states dropdown? Yes country could be a dropdown too but in general, that's how your mat-select and formcontrol depend on each other, correct?

Comment: @jimmy not really. The dropdowns are not depend on each other.
The formControl "selectedValue" could have a value "Id of  a Foo" but this Foo could not be exist. So I have to send a request to the server to get the missed Foo and show it only in the particular dropDown. (not in all dropDowns). 

Thats why i have parameters in the getFoo(rowIndex, dropDownIndex) function, that tells in which row is the drop down and in which position is the dropDopwn so i get the current value from formControl and look if the selected value is exist in the particular dropDown list..

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say, you enter the `selectedValue` => the dropdown has to update according to that value. This is a typical `valueChanges` use case. You can read more about how to use FormReactive's valueChanges or post your demo in stackblitz, fake your data, make it as minimal as possible, we can work on it together

Answer (score 0):

Try to add shareReplay:

```
missedFoo$: Observable<Foo[]> =      this._ksFoosService.getById(someId).pipe(
          tap((res) => this.obsFoos.next([...foos, res])),
          map(() => foos),
    shareReplay(1)
    );
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it keeps sending requests to the server. 

The Problem is inside iif() function. 
When i look in the list to find the target Foo. If i find it it will escape the requests to the backend and if not it keep create Observables and send request to the backend. However with first request i add the result to the list so next time when check it will be exist and avoid multi request. However this occur very late after it get response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Using [share()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/share) will allow you to share the results of an observable without triggering the observable chain more than once. It would look something like this:

```
missedFoo$: Observable<Foo[]> = this._ksFoosService.getById(someId).pipe(
  tap((res) => this.obsFoos.next([...foos, res])),
  map(() => foos),
  share()
);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it keeps sending requests to the server. 

The Problem is inside iif() function. 
When i look in the list to find the target Foo. If i find it it will escape the requests to the backend and if not it keep create Observables and send request to the backend. However with first request i add the result to the list so next time when check it will be exist and avoid multi request. However this occur very late after it get response from the server.